# Laravel 5.1 - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf PDF Generation Error

Tags: laravel-5, dompdf

#### In my composer:

```
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.6.*",
```

#### Here is My config/app Setup:

```
Providers Array:       'Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider',

Aliases Array:          'PDF' => 'Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade',
```

#### Here is My route Setup:

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');

Route::get('/dompdf', function() {

$html='<p>Foo Bar</p>';

PDF::loadHTML($html)->setPaper('a4')
->setOrientation('landscape')
->setWarnings(false)
->save('myfile.pdf');

});
```

While I hit /dompdf url. I got this Error.

[image]

My another Question is if I want to use DOM PDF library in My Controller Method. What setup or Step I Need To Follow??

Comment: You have an issue in their site that fits your problem:
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/20

Comment: Follow these issue.. // somewhere early in your project's loading, require the Composer autoloader
// see: http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// disable DOMPDF's internal autoloader if you are using Composer
define('DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD', false);

// include DOMPDF's default configuration
require_once '/path/to/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php'; but didnt worked

Comment: It looks like the dompdf class is loading, but not the configuration file. I'm not familiar with laravel so maybe someone who is can clarify, but maybe in your route add `require_once '/path/to/composer/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php`.

Comment: FYI, with the next release you should no longer need the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the below command and try

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```